# Connect to two MySQL db's

Tags: database, jdatabase

I want to use a second database for the product data.
Is it possible to connect to two database and using of `JFactory::getDbo();` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need two separate databases for a Joomla instance?

Comment: @Lodder  The maintenance of the product data is not really under my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

Official doc
https://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database

Also note this question has been asked before.
E.G. [I am trying to connect two database with one Joomla site](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21583/i-am-trying-to-connect-two-database-with-one-joomla-site)

Comment: Hyperlink-only answers are low value because they may break.  Are you happy to vote to close with the duplicate question?

Comment: You are right it came be closed by duplicated